# Paging state is not recovering until queue is empty in ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: activemq-artemis

We are facing an issue in ActiveMQ Artemis `2.17.0`. One of the queue went to paging state when it reached the max memory settings - `max-size-bytes`. After some time message count subside very much when consumer processed it. But it is not recovering the paging state until the queue is empty. Is it an expected behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. All the messages associated with the address must be consumed before the broker will leave the configured paging mode.